# Using a secondary DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system

While using the namebench app I realized that my secondary (backup) DNS server is a lot faster  in most situations then my primary. Should I just make my secondary DNS server to be my primary or do they have different tasks and it's not recommended to switch? Both are the default ones provided by my ISP and I am guessing the second one is faster because it's under less load.

Comment: The ordering does not matter. A server will be chosen at random from the list of nameservers, and if it cannot reply in a timely fashion the next will be tried. If you're noticing a difference in performance, another factor is in play.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that's a reasonable assessment and course of action.  Another thing to evaluate is whether recursors other than those belonging to your ISP are faster still, like Google's public DNS servers.

Answer (score 0):

There is not supposed to be any difference between the recursive DNS resolvers handed out through DHCP.

Some operating systems treat them as a prioritized list. Others treat them as a pool of equal servers, which there should be load balanced between.

If the ISP does not consider this different treatment and adjust their deployment accordingly, it is possible to end up in a situation where load is skewed between them.

If you are currently getting DNS servers and other information through DHCP, then changing the settings would require you to stop using DHCP to get it. That will cause your setup to break, if the DNS addresses you configure now stop working some day. This is not a major problem, as long as you know how to change the setting back, if it should cause you trouble.

Some OS will allow you to keep using DHCP for IP assignment and routing without using the DNS information from the DHCP server. If you are currently getting DNS from DHCP, then that is the option you should switch to, if you want to use other DNS servers.

It is worth considering other options as suggested by Shane. Google have public DNS resolvers on 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.